# Azure Machine Learning Studio Says "Value Required" for Cross Validate Module

Tags: azure, cross-validation, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm having a bit of trouble setting up this cross validate module in MS Machine Learning Studio.

I'm not sure which value it's referring to as needing, since the links connected to it just fine, and those were the values I thought I was submitting.

Nor do I think it's referring to the Random Seed, as I've gotten models to work fine without changing that value.

Any tips on how to make that module work?

This is the resource I'd been looking at before coming here:
https://gallery.azure.ai/Experiment/333e0a99ceac457d8992ef83bfbd98b6

[An image of the module flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBHfc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Label column in Cross Validate, i.e. the column that you're trying to train your model to be able to predict. In your case, that's most likely the Price column.